# How to process laravel queue in online server

Tags: laravel, process, server, queue, listen

I want to send mail using queue. Laravel queue works well in local server with the command "php artisan queue:listen". How to process the queue in online server

Comment: Can you set up a cron job on your server to run the queue command?

Comment: I already set a cron job in my server. But it can't work

Comment: Please provide details on the cron job and why it doesn't work. What happens when you try to run it?

Answer (score 2):

you have to install `supervisor` in you server. 

[See here for installation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#supervisor-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [task scheduller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling) but it still requires to setup a cron job

Comment: protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
                 {
       
                                     $schedule->command('queue:work --daemon')                                                                                                                                                                             ->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
                   }

Comment: protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
       $schedule->command('queue:work --daemon')
       ->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
    }
    This is my schedule command and my cron conmmand is 
    * * * * * php /home/myusername/public_html/myproject/project1/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule you queue command in kernel file as below,

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3')->cron('* * * * * *');
    }
```

and set laravel cron on server as below,

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

So this main cron will run mail:queue every minute.